# CSS Layout with Table Heights

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm trying to make the following layout work....

http://jsbin.com/aqoseb/9/edit

In chrome it works perfectly, but in Firefox/IE10 the scrollbars don't appear on the central content region.

This is a layout for a dialog, hence the nest in the fixed container.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898651/overflow-x-visible-overflow-y-auto-does-not-work-is-this-standards-complia

Comment: I don't think this is related to the referenced question.  Changing overflow properties to scroll for x and y still does not get the right height for the .scrollnicely class.  I think its related to the table layout.